# xcode 9.0.1 simualtor error on building the project at random times

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

[image: simulator IOS 11 Xcode 9.0.1]

When I start simulator at random times when I compile/run project my simulator goes like in the attached image...if i press the menu button it doesn't change it remains the same. The error make it impossible to use the simulator.

I tried restarting, resetting simulator work but then it happens again.

Comment: ..but some times resseting content and settings will not fix it ana i am stuck ...

Comment: I sometimes have this issue and end up restarting my machine to get things working again.

Comment: When it happens i quicly restart simulator in Simulator- > Restart.   And it works ... but after that restarting never work. U should try vincent solution... use a real device hahhabaha

Comment: Another advice from vincent... try android:)))

Answer (score 0):

What i do to solve the problem:
 1. stop project
 2. Hardware -> restart simulator 
it happened to me 2 times in a row and this method worked and i didnt had to restart laptop.... but you have to do it fast ....

Answer (score -1):

Try to run the default app.

If it doesn't work: there are only two solutions:

1. run it on an actual device
2. download the iOS 10.3 simulator (Xcode->Preferences->components->Ios 10.3 simulator)

remember to set this answer to correct if it helped. ;)

Comment: 1. So .. your your solution is to run it on a real device... ?? I know i can run it on a real device but i need simulators for testing....  2. I have all tools updated.. xcode and simulators... and for you i will specifie that my mac OS is also updated... pls dont hunt for points dont answer if you dont have a solution!